# Nowrap / Don't break the line after a input

Tags: html, css

If i have several input (radio or option) followed by their label, all on the same line. How i make it so it don't break the line after the radio, but break **if needed** after the label.

```
<input type="radio" id="i1"/><label for="i1">First radio</label>
<input type="radio" id="i2"/><label for="i2">Second radio</label>
<input type="radio" id="i3"/><label for="i3">Third radio</label>
```

I can think of wrapping both `input` and `label` in a `span` with `nowrap`, but wonder if there's another way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```css
#MyDiv {width: 250px;}
```

```html
<div id="MyDiv">
    <nobr><input type="radio" id="i1"/><label for="i1">First radio</label></nobr>
    <nobr><input type="radio" id="i2"/><label for="i2">Second radio</label></nobr>
    <nobr><input type="radio" id="i3"/><label for="i3">Third radio</label></nobr>
</div>
```

The `<nobr>` tag will ensure the break won't happen between the button and label.

CSS way is also possible, wrapping it with another `<span>` and using `white-space: nowrap;` should work fine.

Comment: sure, i mention that in the question.

Comment: You probably edited with this information after I answered, didn't see it. Anyway, see my edit.

Comment: Neither worked. Try it yourself, or provide the full answer: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: @DamirOlejar yes it does work. We really don't need w3schools editor, we can embed and run code directly in the posts. I have added a full example now as you asked.

Comment: Hmm... I do not know what the issue is then, maybe the bootsrap styles I am importing.  I have posted my solution below... Thank you!

Comment: @DamirOlejar weird, might be worth a new question, table layout is quite bad, and you might get  much better answers, if you'll post the relevant code you're using.

Comment: @ShadowWizard  I wish I could post the code, but it is for internal use for the company I am with... The issue was with the bootstrap, and it is now fixed.

Comment: Fair enough @Damir but don't be surprised if you get downvotes... many programmers really don't like using tables for those purposes. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/catalinred/kNUaz/

Comment: I think you should always break - to have the radios one over each other - for a better selection. This can improve usability for this form (http://www.useit.com/alertbox/20040927.html). Just my two cents.

Comment: i know sure, but i have about 20 or more checkboxes that should go between two images, and there are several images...

Answer (score 0):

Nothing worked for me (or at least I thought so, until I fixed it)...
My dirty solution therefore was to use the tables, 1 row, multiple columns. You may need to adjust the padding/spacing.

Edit: **Warning** this is a bad way of doing things, but if nothing works it might help.

```
                        <table border="0"  >
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><input name="gender" type="radio" value="male" checked> Male </td>
                                <td><input name="gender" type="radio" value="female"> Female </td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
```